# Flutter Firestore issue reading Map values

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know what I may be doing wrong here, but when I read data from Firestore map and try to turn it into a list, the order of values change randomly.

For example, this is what my Firestore map looks like:

[image]

My Flutter code to read this and turn into a list looks like this:

```
List l = [];
 document
     .data()
     .values
     .elementAt(i)
     .forEach((k, v) => l.add({k: v}));
```

This sometime returns:

```
[{tries: 3}, {score: 4.5}, {r: 34.0}, {t: 05:29}, {y1: 130.0}, {x1: 110.0}, {y2: 50.0}, {x2: 100.0}]
```

Sometimes returns:

```
[{score: 4.5}, {tries: 3}, {r: 34.0}, {t: 05:29}, {y1: 130.0}, {x1: 110.0}, {y2: 50.0}, {x2: 100.0}]
```

The order of values change.

I have noticed that this sometimes happens when I modify some values or deleted some values and update a few items etc. But I have not been able to pinpoint the cause yet.

I might be doing the list creation incorrectly I think.
I really tried to search before posting, was not able to find a question similar to this.
Any pointers here appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you updating the values before fetching them? It is possible that the order of the objects in the map is changing because you're updating them beforehand.

Comment: Yes I am updating them and then fetching. Is there a way to make sure I can have control over the order of the list?

Comment: Yes, you can add a timestamp/index on every object and sort them after fetching.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of instead of converting the vales to a List, how about just keeping them as Map<String, dynamic>?